# Finding lowest integer from list (missing numbers)

Tags: python

I have the start, end no and available list.

```
start_no = 6001, end_no = 6190
List = [u'6001', u'6005', u'6008', u'6002']
```

From this list I want to fetch the least min number from missing values between start and end numbers. 
(i.e) I need the value of 6003

How to achieve this result in Python?

Answer (score 4):

Since your range of values is well defined, you only need to check the first number in the range that is not in the list:

```
my_set = set(map(int, List))
val = next(i for i in range(start_no, end_no+1) if i not in my_set)
```

This avoids building a whole new list and running over its entire length with `min`.

If the list is relatively large, you may consider making it a set to reduce *membership lookup time*.

Comment: +1, the right way of course, but don't call your `set` '`lst`'; also consider adding a default value for `next()`

Comment: @Chris_Rands You have a point with the name, but adding a default value is up to them; sometimes we don't want to suppress errors.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye as chris pointed out `set()` uses atleast O(n) for making a set from list, and occupies memory. Code works good without that :)

Comment: @Pavan The creation O(n) is a one-time cost, unlike the repeated O(n) lookups for each candidate in the list.

Comment: @MosesKoledoye okay, I understand for set lookup is O(1)avg compared with o(n) for list. so it takes less time. Cool! UP you go :p

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
start_no = 6001 
end_no =6190
min_val = ""
my_list = [u'6001', u'6005', u'6008', u'6002']
for x in xrange(start_no, end_no+1):
   if str(x) not in my_list:
        min_val = str(x) 
        break
```

**EDIT**: For list comprehension.

```
min_val = min([x for x in range(start_no, end_no + 1) if str(x) not in my_list])
```

Comment: don't call your variable `List`.

Comment: @asongtoruin I believe you got `List` confused with `list`

Comment: No, I didn't - even if it's not a direct conflict with the built-in name, it's confusing at best.

Comment: @asongtoruin I just took the variable name from the question. anyway edited :)

Comment: You answer is correct but why generating all the numbers in the range when you just need the first one?

Comment: @VMRuiz is correct, this is very wasteful just use `next()` with a generator expression to get the first and lowest number

Comment: Good answer, but I'd suggest to choose an other name for the variable `min` as well.

Comment: Why this change in the answer? It worked with list comprehensions, but with this new version it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: @vmonteco try now. VMRuiz and Chris_Rands check my edit :)

Comment: @Pavan Do you mind if I edit your answer to add the snippet with list comprehensions? I personnally find this more elegant.

Comment: @vmonteco as pointed by other in the comment, list comprehensions took more memory space, and I believe it'll take more time compared to this one. But you can edit and put your snippet in a separate block. or I can only add it. :)

Comment: @vmonteco added the list comprehension statement as a separate snippet.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
start_no = 6001 
end_no = 6190

result = start_no
list_values = [u'6001', u'6005', u'6008', u'6002']

while str(result) in list_values and result < end_no:
    result += 1

if result not in list_values:
    print "Result is %d" % result
else:
    print "There isn't any missing number"
```

Comment: Its not fully clear if it would be a fail or the desired behavior as numbers in between can be inclusive or exclusives. Anyway, it would be as easy as starting with `result =  start_no + 1`

Answer (score 0):

For getting the least number, just loop from the start to the end. the first one that is not on the list should be the least one.

```
start_no = 6001
end_no = 6190
list_num = [u'6001', u'6005', u'6008', u'6002']
for i in range(start_no, end_no + 1):
    if not str(i) in list_num:
        return i
```